# how can select data from two tables in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables news and topics

```
      news                        topics

id  title  text                id  title  text
--- ----- ----                 --- -----  ----
1   abc    aa                   1   hgd    hh   
2   def    bb                   2   ddf    ff
3   gfs    cc                   3   gty    gg
4   sdfv   dd                   4   bbc    tt
```

i want to select title the two tables

i tried this code but it sin't work

```
<?
$select_newtopics = $mysqli->query("select * from news,arts order by id desc");
$num_newtopics = $select_newtopics->num_rows;

while ($rows_newtopics = $select_newtopics->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$id_newtopics       = $rows_newtopics ['id'];
$title_newtopics    = $rows_newtopics ['title'];

echo $title_newtopics."<br>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Look for JOIN and UNION and how they work in your MySQL documentation for SELECT.

Comment: How are these two tables related? Do they share the same IDs?

Comment: check about foreign key concept of mysql .

Comment: @ale8oneboy i want post new data from both in one place

Comment: FWIW, AFAIK `<?` is deprecated behaviour, everyone is supposed to use `<?php` nowadays.

Comment: @Smar it's just model to make my question clear

Comment: @MahmoudSamy: I just spotted that you’re using a deprecated thing and mentioned about it, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a result set that contains all the (unique) titles from both tables, regardless of whether or not the tables are related in any way...

```
SELECT title FROM news

UNION 

SELECT title FROM topics
```

See [MySQL's UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) documentation for more details, options, and specifics.

---

To display the results, it's mostly the same as your previous code:

```
$select_newtopics = $mysqli->query("SELECT title FROM news

UNION 

SELECT title FROM topics");

$num_newtopics = $select_newtopics->num_rows;

while ($row = $select_newtopics->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['title'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: how can i post the data

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't see a key tying the 2 tables together, you can use `UNION` reference google for additional info, example below:

```
SELECT title FROM news
UNION
SELECT title FROM topics;
```

Comment: how can i post the data

Answer (score 0):

Your table have to share an id for example added news_id to topics table to link the two table

```
    news                        topics
```

id  title  text                id  title  text news_id
--- ----- ----                 --- -----  ---- -------
1   abc    aa                   1   hgd    hh  1 
2   def    bb                   2   ddf    ff  2
3   gfs    cc                   3   gty    gg  3
4   sdfv   dd                   4   bbc    tt  4

Please update your database structure and you can use JOIN

```
<?
 $select_newtopics = $mysqli->query("SELECT news.id AS newsId,
                                 news.title AS  newsTitle, 
                                 news.text AS newsText, 
                                 topics.id AS topicId, 
                                 topics.title AS topicTitle, 
                                 topics.text AS topictext
                                 FROM topics
                                 LEFT JOIN news ON topics.news_id = news.id
                                 ORDER BY topics.id
                                 DESC");
 $num_newtopics = $select_newtopics->num_rows;

 while ($rows_newtopics = $select_newtopics->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

        $id_newtopics       = $rows_newtopics ['topicId'];
        $title_newtopics    = $rows_newtopics ['topicTitle'];

        echo $title_newtopics."<br>";
```

}
?>